# Prove that for any random variable Z taking values in the range {1, 2, 3, . . .}, E(Z) = (Σ from i = 1 to infinity) P(Z ≥ i)?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation

How would I even begin proving this? I've been thinking about this for an hour now with no luck.

I attempted to get E(Z) and go from there, but I can't seem to prove it

Comment: Try rearranging each sum and see both sums have the same terms.

Comment: Hint:  $P(i)=P(Z=i)=P(Z≥i)-P(Z≥i+1)$.  Thus, say, $1\times P(1)+2\times P(2)=P(Z≥1)-P(Z≥2) + 2P(Z≥2)-2P(Z≥3)=P(Z≥1)+P(Z≥2)-2P(Z≥3)$ and so on.